# Is it possible to connect a biometric device to a mobile phone app?

Tags: mysql, mobile-application, biometrics

Is there a way of connecting a thumb scanning device to windows phone or any other mobile (please state the model) and sending scanned thumb images to a remote mysql database from a mobile application??
In my project, I have a Php website on server side and a mobile application on the client side. This mobile application is supposed to submit a form containing the person's data ( including biometric thumb image) to this remote database that I have created on Apache web server.

Comment: It is easy to send data using JSON objects and manipulate the data on the server side. This is nothing different than a classic mobile application with a web service. Here what you need to figure out is to get the person's data. If you could scan the thumb image, you can do the other stuff easily with searching for android web services.

Comment: What if I want to use a windows phone then which type of web services would I need?
Can you suggest any online tutorial?

Comment: I was told that we can not connect biometric devices to smart phones because required drivers are not available and biometric device can only be connected to personal computers. So its not rue?

Comment: I'm not an expert about biometric devices but web services is the same for all mobile devices. You can google it as web services